# Failed with FTP palettes

Tags: tibco

For the palette "FTP Dir", I put "D:\FullPath\MyFolder" as Directory parameter. I get the following error after deployment :

```
Cannot perform FTP Operation: DIR. Error Info: Unexpected reply code. Returned Code: 550. Detail Description: CWD failed. "/D:/FullPath/MyFolder": directory not found. Expected Code: 250.
```

The name is concat with '/' and '\' are replaces by '/'. I develop on Windows, deploy on linux server and my FTP directory is on one Windows server.

When I try to use the 'FTP Put Palette', I have the error 'Invalid Filename'

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not specify the absolute directory path in the `Directory` parameter but the path relative to the root directory of your FTP server.

In your case, assuming the FTP root directory is `D:\FullPath` and you want to access `MyFolder`, then you should set `Directory` to `/MyFolder`.